# How to add light without losing model color?

Tags: rendering, lighting

Whenever I add a light, it either isn't strong enough to illuminate anything or is so strong that the models lose any color and turn white in rendering.
I would like to add consistent light without removing the color I added to my models

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You somehow reduced exposure by *a lot* and changed your color space.

Go to *Render* tab > *Color Managment* > *Exposure* and set it to 0 (default value). You probably don't want to change that setting unless you really know what you are doing.

#### Exposure

You'll find an example of different exposure [in the official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/color_management.html) (first image). Basically it represents the sensitivity of the camera. Can be useful to tweak the overall look of your renders.

#### Look

The only parameter from the *Color Managment* I would advise to tweak is the *Look*, which is contrast. There are some presets to choose from.

#### View Transform (color space)

The default color space is *AgX*, which emulates photorealistic lights and colors. It's perfect for anything that you want to feel realistic. One of the caracteristic of it, is that as in real life, any colored surface will turn to white when overexposed. It's what we experienced as well, as humans.

The alternative is *Standard*. This color space will never turn your colors to white even when overexposed, which can feel artificial and sometimes wanted. Works well for toon/cel-shading looks.

Comment: I did what you said and it's still white ;-;

Comment: Your big character (Cube.005) is white. Give it some color. And decrease sun strength.

Comment: The mannequin is colored a bruised purple. Regardless, both of cube.005 and "full" are still white in my render. Did I mess something up when I originally made them or something?

Comment: No, the big character is white with no texture (at least in the blend file you provided). I'm not sure what your issue is. Consider adding screenshots and more informations in your original question.

Comment: do you think a lack of texture could be the issue? Sorry, I'm quite new to blender and appreciate your help :)

Comment: I don't see any issue in your file besides the content of my original answer. If you followed it, then you can just change de *Base Color* of your big character's material. One point though, your *World* is emitting light. You may want to reduce its strength too.

Comment: does that mean the background surface light? I'll try to disable it again.

Comment: Kinda. I mean the *Material* of your *World*. For now it emits quite a bit of light.

Comment: im sorry, i dont know how to change that other than removing the background from the surface tab in the "World" sidebar. By materials you dont mean the meshes do you?

Comment: Your *World* has a *Material* that you can change, the same way you change the *Material* of a *Mesh* object. If this is new for you, I would **strongly** recommend you to watch/read some tutorials about the basis of Blender.